# How can I clear asp.net session value in OnUnload event in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I'd like to clear `ASP.NET` session value when browser closed. I've onunload function defined in my `html` page, but I don't know how can I clear session value in this Javascript method ?

```
<body onunload="myUnloadFunction()">


<script>
function myUnloadFunction()
{
  // Needs asp.net session code here
}
</script>
```

Please let me know Is it possible else any other preferable way of doing.

Comment: @KhanhTO - He cannot clear the session value in JavaScript, but he can call back to the server in his JavaScript code as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

Code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ClearYourSessionValue()
{
    // This will leave the key in the Session cache, but clear the value
    Session["YourKey"] = null;

    // This will remove both the key and value from the Session cache
    Session.Remove("YourKey");
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PageName.aspx/ClearYourSessionValue",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
         // Do something interesting here.
    }
});
```

If you want more information about `ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods` and how to invoke them via `AJAX` then read [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)