# Browser tab exit event should close session

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I wanted to close session if User closes tab including condition that same domain window is not open state in same browser. How do I achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't.  The browser doesn't tell the server that it's closing a tab.

Comment: I would guess you will have to use mix of client side script and server script. Something like detecting the tab closing event in JS and making a ajax call to server method that would clear all session information. Try this approach you may be able to achieve what you want. :)

Comment: Any ideas, how do I use this combination

Comment: @Hitin: `"you may be able to achieve what you want"` - It's worth mentioning that "may" here really means "maybe, sometimes, unreliably".  The OP may use this approach and test it once or twice on his workstation and it may *appear* to work.  But it won't be reliable in production across other browsers, other network connections, etc.

Comment: I suppose, banking sites are using same approach. How they deal with it?

Comment: @David no! May doesn't mean unreliable or not working. Millions of website work on client and server code combination, why wont it work?

Comment: @MayP yes, you are right about banking sites, it will work. You just need to make sure you enable session in your web services. Do some r&d and you will be able to achieve. Use jquery or JS to make call to async PageMethod.

Comment: @MayP check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772090/how-can-i-clear-asp-net-session-value-in-onunload-event-in-javascript

Comment: @Hitin: Because there's no guarantee that the browser is going to tell the server that a tab/window/etc. has been closed.  You can try using the `unload` event for example, but different browsers may handle your code in response to that event differently.  Essentially what the OP is trying to do is stop (or delay) the user from closing the browser.  In-browser JavaScript has *very* limited capabilities in such regards, for obvious security reasons.  It *can* work, but not reliably.

Comment: @David If the OP makes a call to web server code on 'unload' event using ajax, the server code is anyway going to execute, is it not?

Comment: @Hitin: If the DOM fires the event before the application destroys it, and if the execution of the code reaches that point before the application stops it, and assuming the AJAX call is successful and doesn't result in an error (which isn't caught because the client-side code doesn't exist anymore at that point).  You keep asking if this *can* work.  Under the right circumstances, yes, it *can*.  But not *always*.  If the OP is relying on this for security to protect user data, it's at least worth warning him of this.  Just because something works once on your machine doesn't mean it's secure.

Comment: @David that's a lot of assumption. I won't dispute what you mentioned but in under conditions it is possible to achieve what OP wants to do. It works on my machine as well as on lots of production machines out there. Besides OP didn't mention anything else, so there is no way to know if this is something very serious or may be something more of a personal project.